# setting index default home page angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Pretty simple thing I'm trying to do. Fairly new to angular.

I just want to set the initial page that loads to be something other than the main that it is set to out of box when I generate an application

Comment: ive run yo angular:route survey. and that generated a view and script in my application which im going to begin modifying. I want when I run grunt serve (and for anyone navigating to my page), for it to go to my custom generated page instead of the default main page it has

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your config (presumably `app.js` with your scaffold), change the `templateUrl` to be the template/view that you desire.

eg:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/someOtherTemplate.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
   ...
});
```

If you're using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) then it's similar:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/someOtherTemplate.html'
      })

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [angular router](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) then it'll be something like this:

```
angular.module('yourMainAppModule').config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "youTemplate.html",
    controller: "YourHomeController"
  })
});
```

You can read more about setting up your app's routes by looking at [`when()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) in the Angular Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Above methods where not working for me, giving the url field an empty value worked great with ui-router :

```
        $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'views/homepage.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })
```